# Desactivar funcion imagen wordpress-astra - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Uso una plantilla de e-commerce de astra pero tengo un problema viendo las miniaturas de la tienda, al pasar el puntero carga la 2 imagen que uno adjunta al crear articulos nuevos, tapa el texto de abajo, puedo identificar la linea con 'herramientas de desarrollador - chrome' y borrandola me permite que solo muestre la 1er foto como quiero que quede, adjunto unas imagenes:

1. Ejemplo de lo explicado antes y después de borrar la linea correspondiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. La linea sombreada es la que pruebo borrando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Si es posible quisiera meter en css adicional 'ver foto' la solución pues aqui meti unas lineas que me solucionaron otras cosas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más recomendable sería hacerlo mediante el editor de temas de wordpress, eliminando el contenido desde el php; sin embargo, podrías llegar a *parchearlo* **(Para la los puntos 1 y 2)** añadiendo un CSS.

```
.show-on-hover {

visibility: hidden !important;

}
```

Y para tu tercer punto, lamentablemente no comprendo bien que es lo que quieres hacer, pero si es lo que creo, el añadirle un componente o texto que diga "Ver fotos" eso tendrías que hacerlo de igual forma con el editor de temas, ya que veo más viable hacer un `<div>` con un atributo css `position: absolute;`.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Si funciono¡ pegando la linea desde el editor basico wp 'css adicional, espero queden los cambios al subir al hosting, esque me da cosa tocar eso del php directamente pues lo que entiendo se puden perder cambios al actualizarse WP y no tener eso del (child-theme).  Lo del punto 3  En resumen lo resolvi como te comento, Mil gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor no uses el area de respuestas para agregar preguntas, por favor lee [answer]